# Excel VBA Compare two array and create result array

Tags: excel, vba

I have two array (each array have three column , have about 18.000 row). I want to compare array1, array2 , then creat a result array. 
For more detail, Pleae go to my link for xlsb file.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/r38m45t2s93wy5y/compare_array-.xlsb/file

Comment: The Question should be able to stand on its own and not require the need to download a file, which many people will not do for safety reasons.  Please show the code you have and explain where the error is occurring.  Might help to read about creating a [mcve]

Comment: Thank for your suggest . But right now i do not thought out that code for my problem

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But right now, 
I haven't thought of it yet. You can take some time to review my reply in this thread

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go row by row (i.e. compare row 1 of array A to row 1 of array B), one way is to use VBA to loop through each row and compare the values. You can output the result in a new array (maybe you can call it array D since you have three input arrays).

In the VBA code, first identify how many rows of data.

```
firstrow = 1
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
```

In the following code I'm going to assume:
array A is columns 1-3
array B is columns 4-6
and I'll output array D to columns 10-12

```
for i = firstrow to lastrow:
   'compare array A value 1 to array B value 1
   If ActiveSheet.cells(i, 1).value == ActiveSheet.cells(i, 4).value Then 
       'Write result for array D value 1 if equal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 10).value = "A & B are equal"
   Else 
       'Write result for array D value 1 if unequal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 10).value = "A & B are NOT equal"

   'Make comparison between array A value 2 to array value 2
   If ActiveSheet.cells(i, 2).value == ActiveSheet.cells(i, 5).value Then 
       'Write result for array D value 2 if equal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 11).value = "A & B are equal"
   Else 
       'Write result for array D value 2 if unequal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 11).value = "A & B are NOT equal"    

   'Make comparison between array A value 3 to array value 3
   If ActiveSheet.cells(i, 3).value == ActiveSheet.cells(i, 6).value Then 
       'Write result for array D value 3 if equal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 12).value = "A & B are equal"
   Else 
       'Write result for array D value 3 if unequal
       ActiveSheet.cells(i, 12).value = "A & B are NOT equal"    
next i
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. But it's not my kind of comparation in result array. My result array have six column that contain array1,array 2. You can take some time to review my reply in this thread

Answer (score 0):

[Image of my array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGRDt.png)

And here is one of extracting of my file

```html
Array 1      Array 1    Array 1     Array 2    Array 2  Array 2
Code 1       INV 1       Q1   Code 2     INV 2 Q2
2000000001206 NK 1801/001 40 2000000001206 NK 1801/001 40
8935001878711 NK 1801/001 40 8935001878711 NK 1801/001 40
8935001882381 NK 1801/001 20 8936120920343 NK 1801/001 10
9786040108203 NK 1801/001 5 9786040108203 NK 1801/001 5
9786049448577 NK 1801/002 3       9786049448577 NK 1801/003 3
9786049448607 NK 1801/002 3  9786049448607 NK 1801/003 3
9786049448812 NK 1801/002 3  9786049448812 NK 1801/003 3
2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5  2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5
8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5  8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5
6691188352292 NK 1801/005 12 2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5
2000000001206 NK 1802/006 1  8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5
2000000001278 NK 1802/006 2  2000000002268 NK 1801/005 1
2000000001485 NK 1802/006 3  6691188352162 NK 1801/005 4
8936120920343 NK 1803/007 3  6691188352216 NK 1801/005 2
8936120920350 NK 1803/007 5  6691188352292 NK 1801/005 12
2000000002454 NK 1803/007 5  2000000001206 NK 1802/006 1
2000000002455 NK 1803/008 5  2000000001276 NK 1802/006 20
2000000002456 NK 1803/008 5  2000000001485 NK 1802/006 5
9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3  8936120920336 NK 1803/007 5
9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3  8936120920343 NK 1803/007 5
9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5  2000000002454 NK 1803/007 5
9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5  2000000002455 NK 1803/008 1
9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5  9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3
9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5  9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5
2000000000987 NK 1801/010 42 9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5
2000000000988 NK 1801/010 42 2000000000987 NK 1801/010 42
2000000001527 NK 1801/010 30 2000000000988 NK 1801/010 42
2000000001990 NK 1801/010 1  2000000001527 NK 1801/010 30
2000000001991 NK 1801/010 1  2000000001990 NK 1801/010 1
...................more and more under...................
---------------------and here is my result array--------------
Result Array Result Array Result Array Result Array
Code 1       INV 1       Q1   Code 2       INV 2     Q2
2000000001206 NK 1801/001 40 2000000001206 NK 1801/001 40
8935001878711 NK 1801/001 40 8935001878711 NK 1801/001 40
8935001882381 NK 1801/001 20   
                   8936120920343 NK 1801/001 10
9786040108203 NK 1801/001 5   9786040108203 NK 1801/001 5
9786049448577 NK 1801/002 3 9786049448577 NK 1801/003 3
9786049448607 NK 1801/002 3 9786049448607 NK 1801/003 3
9786049448812 NK 1801/002 3 9786049448812 NK 1801/003 3
2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5 2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5
8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5  8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5
                   2000000001429 NK 1801/004 5
                   8934994208161 NK 1801/004 5
                   2000000002268 NK 1801/005 1
                   6691188352162 NK 1801/005 4
                   6691188352216 NK 1801/005 2
6691188352292 NK 1801/005 12 6691188352292 NK 1801/005 12
2000000001206 NK 1802/006 1 2000000001206 NK 1802/006 1
2000000001278 NK 1802/006 2   
                   2000000001276 NK 1802/006 20
2000000001485 NK 1802/006 3 2000000001485 NK 1802/006 5
                   8936120920336 NK 1803/007 5
8936120920343 NK 1803/007 3       8936120920343 NK 1803/007 5
8936120920350 NK 1803/007 5   
2000000002454 NK 1803/007 5       2000000002454 NK 1803/007 5
2000000002455 NK 1803/008 5 2000000002455 NK 1803/008 1
2000000002456 NK 1803/008 5   
9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3 9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3
9786040021854 NK 1903/009 3   
9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5  9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5
9786040108203 NK 1903/009 5   
9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5 9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5
9786040108234 NK 1903/009 5   
2000000000987 NK 1801/010 42 2000000000987 NK 1801/010 42
2000000000988 NK 1801/010 42 2000000000988 NK 1801/010 42
2000000001527 NK 1801/010 30 2000000001527 NK 1801/010 30
2000000001990 NK 1801/010 1 2000000001990 NK 1801/010 1
2000000001991 NK 1801/010 1  2000000001991 NK 1801/010 1
........................ more and more under...............................
```